# Change Python Version in Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am confused by different outputs when I try to check the Python version used in Google Colab.
In my project I need a specific Python version.
Therefore, I want to downgrade Python to a specific version.
I do this with this code:

```
!apt-get update -y
!update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!update-alternatives --config python3
!apt install python3-pip
!apt install python3.7-distutils
```

I then check the version in four different ways:

```
!python --version
import sys
print("User Current Version:-", sys.version)
import platform
print(platform.python_version())
import os
os.system("python --version")
```

and get this output:

```
Python 3.7.17
User Current Version:- 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0]
3.10.12
0
```

Based on my understanding the sys.version method should give back the version that is really used.
Strangely, it is possible for me to install package versions that actually are just possible to install under Python 3.7.17.
What Python version am I actually using, and what do the four different methods actually return?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
```

This command creates symbolic links, so when you type `!python3`, it will run `/usr/bin/python3.7`

> what do the four different methods actually return?

- `!python --version`: because you created symlink, it will use the 3.7 version
- `print("User Current Version:-", sys.version)`: prints the version from which the kernel is running. (colab's default version: 3.10.12)
- `print(platform.python_version())`: same as above. because both are running in the cell of colab. (from what I know, we can't change the colab's kernel version)
- `os.system("python --version")`: prints the exit status of the command you ran. os.system("command") does not print the output from the command you ran.

> it is possible for me to install package under Python 3.7.17? \

you can use `!python -m pip install package`.
but, when you want to run some code using python 3.7, you have to run it from command. like, `!python file.py`